# cakephp select count number of days

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I need to retrieve all records from a table older than 2 days (working days) and also return the number of days it has been stored.

For instance, if today is August 12 2013 (Mon) I need to retrieve all records from  August 8 2013 (Thu) and older, and its count should be 2 (August 10 and  11 Fri).

Answer (score 0):

**My model**    : Author

**My db field** : created(type:date)

**Controller function**

```
public function index() {

    $authors=array();
    $conditions = array(
        'AND' => array(
        'Author.created !='=>date('Y-m-d'), //to ignore today in count.You can remove this if you want to consider
        'Author.created < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY', // you can change INTERVAL as per your need 
        )
    );
    $authors = $this->Author->find('all', array(
            'conditions' =>$conditions));

    foreach ($authors as $key=>$value)
    {
                $arr[$key]=$value['Author']['created']; 
        $ts1 =strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
        $ts2 = strtotime($arr[$key]);
        $seconds_diff = $ts1 - $ts2;
            $days[$key]=floor($seconds_diff/3600/24);
    }

        $this->set(compact('authors', 'days'));
   }
```

**index.ctp file**

```
<?php 
foreach($authors as $key=>$author): ?>
<h2>Name:<?php echo $author['Author']['name'] ?></h2>
<h2>Since:<?php echo $days[$key]; ?> Days</h2>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope this will help you.if you have any problem then please let us know.

Comment: if you find any answer that solved your question then consider upvoting and accepting so people know it's solved